# how to loop through json response data using ajax jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to loop through a json response with ajax jquery but I can't display the result.

Here is the code Im using:

**data.php**

```
function platformsList(){
    $query = "SELECT id, name, slug, icon FROM `platforms` ORDER BY id ASC";
    $statement   = $GLOBALS['PDO']->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $data = array();
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
if(isset($_GET['platforms']) AND $_GET['platforms'] == 'platforms'){
    $platforms = platformsList();
    $response = json_decode($platforms);
    print_r($response);
}
```

**jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "core/data.php",
            method: "GET",
            data :'platforms=platforms',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                for(var i = 0; response.length < i; i++) {
                    $('.platformsList').html('<li>'+response.name+'</li>');
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

What I want is to display the result in the div below:

```
<div>
    <ul class="platformsList"></ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:

WHen I debug I get this result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] =>  Platform 1
            [slug] => dates
            [icon] => dates.webp
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Platform 2
            [slug] => honey
            [icon] => honey.webp
        )
.
.
... etc
```

Comment: In what way does this fail?  When you debug, what is the content of the `response` variable?

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: Might need to check the proper formation of an unordered list `<ul class="platformsList"></li>` ??

Comment: lol, just a typo

Comment: the probleme here is that I can't display the result in html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `response[i].name` to access the array

```
success: function(response) {
                let buffer = '';
                
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    buffer += '<li>'+response[i].name+'</li>';
                }
                
                $('.platformsList').html(buffer);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but instead of .html() I used .append()

Comment: @RichardBranson note that using jquery's `append()` will update the DOM multiple times unnecessarily. This operation is resource intensive and may render your page slow with large datasets. Using a buffer is advisable.

Comment: append() and buffer is recommended, I tried to stick to the source

Answer (score 3):

You are replacing the contents of `.platformsList` in each iteration. You need to either create a buffer or use `append()`.

```
success: function(response) {

    let buffer = '';

    for (var i = 0; response.length < i; i++) {

        buffer += '<li>'+response[i].name+'</li>';

    }

    $('.platformsList').html(buffer);

}
```

Comment: still same problem. Can't display anything

Comment: @RichardBranson `response` seems to be an array. I edited the example code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Dont use GLOBALS like that, instead pass that as a paramter to the function
2. If you have no paramters to bind to the query a simple `->query()` is easier and quicker.
3. You want to send a `json_encode()` JSON String to the AJAX call, your are decoding it back to a PHP array and then sending a `print_r()` Javascript wont understand that.

```
function platformsList($conn){
    $query = "SELECT id, name, slug, icon FROM `platforms` ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result   = $conn->query($query);
    
    $data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
    return $data;
}

if(isset($_GET['platforms']) AND $_GET['platforms'] == 'platforms'){
    $platforms = platformsList($PDO);
    echo json_encode($platforms);
}
```

And the javascript need to process that array

```
success: function(response) {
    for(var i = 0; response.length < i; i++) {
        buf += '<li>'+response[i].name+'</li>';
    }
    $('.platformsList').html(buf);
}
```

Comment: and how about the jquery loop? is it correct? because I still get no result!